# Keep classes added by jQuery after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, divi

I'm building a plugin menu for a Wordpress website using the Divi theme.

I add a class using the following code:

`jQuery("#cdBarsicon").click(function () { jQuery(".cdMobileMenu").addClass("cdMobileActive"); });`

I noticed while testing on a mobile browser that my menu is closed when scrolling down.
What actually happens is that the window is resized when the mobile browser hides the navigation area.

So I realized that all jQuery class changes are reset after the window is resized.

This is probably normal, but how would I keep the menu visible after resizing the window?

I tried using vanilla javascript instead of jQuery, same problem.

`function openMobileMenu() { document.getElementById("cdMobileMenu").classList.add("cdActive"); }`

I also tried using css() and show() instead of addClass, same problem. It gets reset.

I'm considering using a cookie but I feel I'm missing a simpler solution.

Comment: Are you sure the window is getting resized and not reloaded ? Resizing the window does not change the DOM. Unless there are media-queries or event listeners attached.

Comment: @Lapskaus I am resizing the window by hand. The whole window is not being reloaded, however I can see in the inspector that elements are affected when I resize. Here is a video of it happening. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z-sv9WQgBFE2J3WcxaTZMs9CZZkV0-0t/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Without any code that is impossible to debug for anyone. The only ways I can think of, that manipulate the DOM on resize are media queries and event listeners. Since the class gets removed when you resize the window, I would start by reviewing the code that does that, and search for any code referencing the class in question.

Comment: @Lapskaus Thank you for taking an interest. I solved it by loading the code in a different way. The Divi theme was reloading/reseting classes in a weird way within a certain building block (the code block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why but the solution in this case was to use the text block instead of the code block in the Divi builder to add the shortcode that displays my menu.